# Why does the browser create two pieces of div in html but when the code just says one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on javascript a bit and have had some problems I do not understand how to solve. In my HTML code, I only have a id="felt" but as soon as I open the page in my browser, it creates two pieces of id="felt" (please see attached image for more understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NawSr.jpg) It seems Do not be wrong with the writing of the html code, there is something that makes id="felt" created twice in the browser and I can't understand why. The second id="felt" is working but the first one is not working.

codepen: https://codepen.io/tommattias/pen/yjYoEQ 
Thanks for your help!!

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Card Game | The Art of Web</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-animation.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="stage">
<div id="felt">
<div id="card_0"><img onclick="cardClick(0);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_1"><img onclick="cardClick(1);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_2"><img onclick="cardClick(2);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_3"><img onclick="cardClick(3);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_4"><img onclick="cardClick(4);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_5"><img onclick="cardClick(5);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_6"><img onclick="cardClick(6);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_7"><img onclick="cardClick(7);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_8"><img onclick="cardClick(8);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_9"><img onclick="cardClick(9);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_10"><img onclick="cardClick(10);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_11"><img onclick="cardClick(11);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_12"><img onclick="cardClick(12);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_13"><img onclick="cardClick(13);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_14"><img onclick="cardClick(14);" src="back.png"></div>
<div id="card_15"><img onclick="cardClick(15);" src="back.png"></div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="css-animation2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var game = new CardGame("stage");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
   var CardGame = function(targetId)
   {    

  var cards = []
  var card_value =
```

["1C","2C","3C","4C","5C","6C","7C","8C","1H","2H","3H","4H","5H","6H","7H","8H"];

```
  var started = false;
  var matches_found = 0;
  var card1 = false, card2 = false;


  var moveToPlace = function(id) // deal card
  {
     cards[id].matched = false;
     with(cards[id].style) {
     zIndex = "1000";
     top = cards[id].fromtop + "px";
     left = cards[id].fromleft + "px";
     WebkitTransform = MozTransform = OTransform = msTransform = 
     "rotate(60deg)";
     zIndex = "0";
   }
 };



 var cardClick = function(id) 
 {
    if(started)
   {
     showCard(id);
   }
   else {
      // shuffle and deal cards
      card_value.sort(function() { return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5; 
   });
     for(i=0; i < 16; i++)
     {
       (function(idx)
       {
         setTimeout(
           function()
           {
             moveToPlace(idx);
           }, idx * 100);
         })(i);
       }
       started = true;
      }
    };

    // initialise

   var stage = document.getElementById(targetId);
   var felt = document.createElement("div");
   felt.id = "felt";
   stage.appendChild(felt);

  // template for card
  var card = document.createElement("div");
  card.innerHTML = "<img src=\'back.png\'>";

   for(var i=0; i < 16; i++) {
     var newCard = card.cloneNode(true);

     newCard.fromtop = 15 + 120 * Math.floor(i/4);
     newCard.fromleft = 70 + 100 * (i%4);
     (function(idx) {
      newCard.addEventListener("click", function() { cardClick(idx); }, 
  false);
  })(i);

felt.appendChild(newCard);
cards.push(newCard);
}

}
```

EDIT: When i open my browser, i get like this picture shows 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NawSr.jpg the one who has the text "Not working" should not show up. When i open programmer tool i can se that under id="stage", id="felt" creates two times and thats why I have one working and other one not working. My question is why does i get two id="felt" when my code only say one?

Comment: Your script is executed after the html. The html already has the elem with id felt, within your script you create it again

Comment: Your codepen work great?

Comment: No my codepen dosn't work as it should

Comment: @ibowankenobi soo I should delate the code after comment initialise?

Answer (score 2):

It is already existing in your html, and then within the script you create it again. You cannot have 2 different elements with the same id. Remove it from the html and see my comment

Comment: Soo I should delate the code after comment initialise?

Comment: delete <div id="felt"> from your html. It should be ok.